# How man created by God gets along with anthropology?

Tags: creation, nature-of-man

For example even before homo sapiens existed neanderthals or homo heidelbergensis that used tools, had closes etc.

How christianity explain their existence? Is Adam was some kind of homo erectus that than evolved into homo sapiens? Or we had monkeys that almost evolved into humans and then God kill them all and created Adam and Eve?

Comment: We are told *that* God created man [from dust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abiogenesis) (and the world [from nothingness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang)); we aren't told *how*. Religious faith is preoccupied with the former aspect(s); scientific research, with the latter.

Comment: @Lucian my point that we can't ignore new information and i was curious about how christians accept that new knowledge. But i was unaware of the rule "Questions that can be answered from multiple Christian viewpoints are not allowed".

Comment: Since there are very many Christian denominations, questions whose answers might vary along denominational lines must be directed at a specific denomination, or group of denominations. Also, not all information is religiously relevant.

Answer (score 2):

God's word is unchanging; anthropology is not.

This article in the Smithsonian Magazine (not known as a hotbed of creationism) says that scientists are rethinking ideas about Naenderthals:

https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/rethinking-neanderthals-83341003/

Neanderthals were fully human. The differences between Neanderthals and modern humans are no greater than the differences between the most different current groups of humans.

Comment: Are you saying we shouldn't assume Adam and Eve were Homo Sapiens or that man-made taxonomic categories can be misleading?